# Opencart, ocmod, как заменить несколько строк?

Tags: php, opencart

Допустим есть такой код в файле `theme/default/common/header.php`:

```
<li class="actions__list-item">
    <a href="#account" class="js-popup-call">
        <span id="wishcomptotall" class="actions__counter actions__counter--blue" <?php echo ($counTotall) ? '':'style="display:none;"' ; ?> ><?php echo $counTotall; ?></span>
        <svg class="icon-user" version="1.1" id="User" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 18 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 18 20;" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M6.7,2.1c-1,0.8-1.3,2-1.2,2.6c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.8,0.2,1.8S5.4,6.7,5.4,7.4c0.1,1.7,0.7,1,0.8,1.7c0.3,1.8,0.9,1.5,0.9,2.5
                    c0,1.6-0.7,2.4-2.8,3.3C2.2,15.8,0,17,0,19v1h18v-1c0-2-2.2-3.2-4.3-4.1c-2.1-0.9-2.8-1.7-2.8-3.3c0-1,0.6-0.7,0.9-2.5
                    c0.1-0.8,0.7,0,0.8-1.7c0-0.7-0.3-0.9-0.3-0.9s0.2-1,0.2-1.8c0.1-0.8-0.4-2.6-2.3-3.1c-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.9,0.5-1.4
                    C8.4,0.1,7.9,1.3,6.7,2.1z"/>
                </svg>
    </a>
</li>
```

нужно заменить весь тег `svg` на `img`
допустим заменить на `<img src="/images/pic1.png" alt">`
Как это правильно сделать с помощью ocmod?

Comment: подскажите, как это сделать? мне бы понять, что нужно прописывать в тегах `search` и `add`, т.к. какие атрибуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<search><![CDATA[

             <svg class="icon-user" version="1.1" id="User" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 18 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 18 20;" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M6.7,2.1c-1,0.8-1.3,2-1.2,2.6c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.8,0.2,1.8S5.4,6.7,5.4,7.4c0.1,1.7,0.7,1,0.8,1.7c0.3,1.8,0.9,1.5,0.9,2.5 

            ]]></search>

                <add position="replace" offset="4"><![CDATA[

             <img src="/images/pic1.png" alt">

            ]]></add>
```

OCMOD ищет только по одной строке. Как вариант, ищем первую нужную строку, при замене указываем параметр `offset="кол-во строк для замены"`.